# Rooting the HTC Desire Z

Tags: rooting, 2.3-gingerbread, htc-desire-z

Just received one of these (SIM Free, UK Version, Android 2.3 with Sense UI).

Can anybody point me towards the simplest and most easiest way to root this handset?

Comment: Question: Was the Desire Z really delivered with 2.3 already? Because I have one as well and it is still using 2.2.1 saying that this is the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=root+htc+%22desire+z%22) returns these [two](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/permanent-root-htc-desire-z-t-mobile-g2-and-desire-hd-with-visionary/) [methods](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Desire_Z%3a_Rooting).

I would recommend the manual method.  It's more complicated, but gives you a "better" root ( S-Off, SIM-unlock, SuperCID).

Comment: Visionary has been known to brick phones. It worked only on earlier versions of Froyo.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use the Visionary method. You may brick your phones.

If you are currently on Gingerbread then use this [**Guide by Setherio**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1178912) to downgrade to Froyo after which the phone can be rooted. You may also use the PDF available in the above link to do the same along with rooting your device.

If you already happen to be on Froyo with software version 1.3x then you can use the PDF to root your phone.

Comment: Note that "above" has no context here, since answers can be sorted in a number of different ways.

Comment: @AlEverett I've edited the reference to another answer.